# Does Supermicro IPMI require OnBoard video to be enabled?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, ipmi, supermicro

Title pretty much says it all.

I am using a supermicro board with integrated IPMI support. When I connect remotely I can take control of the mouse and keyboard but the video is totally black (no error displayed).

Onboard video is turned off (jumper setting) and I am using the video output of a PCI-E installed card. Is remote K**V**M only available with onboard video?

Comment: I don't know specifically about SuperMicro, but on all of the HP/Compaq and Sun x86 servers I've ever touched, yes, the remote KVM is directly integrated with onboard video. I don't believe there's any other way to really do it, aside from a serial (dumb) terminal. Is there any reason why you're using a PCI-E video card instead of onboard video?

Comment: @Jason we are using Cuda on Tesla GPU and were told by our vendor that there were drivers issue with the onboard video. (But I have not doubled checked).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does.

The IPMI controller and video controller are linked, which is what allows the IPMI controller to actually get you the contents of your screen.  When you are using an external display adapter, all the "rendering" takes place on the card, so the IPMI adapter has no idea is being displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You could plug in an external KVM unit from eg. Lantronix that would work with your PCI video, but I wonder how you need both PCI video *and* remote access.

Comment: ditto for this as a workaround.  I have a device from Startech that allows you to VNC in.  I have it plugged into the console port on my KVM switch in the rack.  Works great and it can switch ports too.

Comment: Were using Cuda (GPU Computing) and back then there was a compatibility issue between the Tesla card and onboard video, so we had to turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the IPMI can only display via the graphics card that is integrated with the IPMI controller, on a SuperMicro this is usually a Matrox or an AST, as listed in the specs of the motherboard.

This can get especially interesting if you use a newer Intel CPU with integrated video, like the E3-1275 v5. The IPMI can only display video via the AST video card, not the onboard Intel card. If you are not using a C226 or C236 chipset, the integrated video on the CPU is likely disabled entirely.